# db.collection(collection).find(<query>) returns empty array as soon as query object contains properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing my own CLI, which performs some actions against a MongoDB database using mongoose.

Everything works except for the fact that as soon as the `query` object is something other than `{}`, I get no results despite documents existing. See below for an example.

```
const program = require('commander');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const jsonParser = require('../helpers/json-parser');

program
  .command('get <collection>')
  .option('-q,--query <query>', 'MongoDB query object', jsonParser)
  .option('-qo,--query-options [query-options]', 'MongoDB query options object', jsonParser)
  .description('Returns documents from a MongoDB collection')
  .action(action);

program.parse(process.argv);

function action(collection, options) {

  let db;

  mongoose.connect('<my-mongo-url>', { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(() => {

    db = mongoose.connection.db;

    console.log(options.query);
    return db.collection(collection).find(options.query, options.queryOptions).toArray().then((docs) => {
      console.log(docs);
      mongoose.disconnect();
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {

    if (db) {
      mongoose.disconnect();
    }
  });
}
```

Running `$ my-cli get users -q '{}'` gives the following result:

> [ { _id: 5cfe593b3bb7cb82644651f0,
>       email: 'foobar@gmail.com',
>       createdAt: 2019-06-10T13:20:59.784Z,
>       updatedAt: 2019-06-10T13:20:59.784Z,
>       role: 'user',
>       __v: 0 } ]

Running `$ my-cli get users -q '{"_id": "5cfe593b3bb7cb82644651f0"}'` gives the following result:

> []

Running `$ my-cli get users -q '{"limit": 1}'` gives the following result:

> []

Running `$ my-cli get users -q '{"skip": 0}'` gives the following result:

> []

I even tried doing `db.collection(collection).find({_id: "5cfe593b3bb7cb82644651f0"})` directly in the code but it still only gives me an empty array.

**I expect all of these queries to output the same thing but they don't. Why is this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_id` in mongoDB is not string, actually it's an instance of [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/index.html). So maybe you should go `db.collection(collection).find({_id: ObjectId("5cfe593b3bb7cb82644651f0")})`.

As for `'{"limit": 1}'` and `'{"skip": 0}'`, I understand that you want to [Modify the Cursor Behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#modify-the-cursor-behavior) to limit or skip the search results.

However, the [db.collection.find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) receive two params: `query` and `projection`, so passing `'{"limit": 1}'` or `'{"skip": 0}'` as the `find` secondary param maybe not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Mongoose but not using Schemas and querying directly to MongoDB (so I don't understand the purpose of using it.). This way, you should compare the _id field with an ObjectId:

```
db.collection(collection).find({_id: ObjectId("5cfe593b3bb7cb82644651f0")})
```

or

```
$ my-cli get users -q '{"_id": ObjectId("5cfe593b3bb7cb82644651f0")}'
```

If I'm not wrong, the other queries are not running because you are passing options as query filters and you should use the `-qo` flag:

```
$ `my-cli get users -qo '{"limit": 1}'
```